# Eclipse crashing on launch

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I recently deleted eclipse and the ADT bundle because some files got accidentally deleted and I wanted to install it fresh over again but when I unzipped the file and opened eclipse I am getting this crash log I am unsure of how to fix this and would appreciate if anybody could help me that has any knowledge on this.

```
Process:               eclipse [1032]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/*/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:            org.eclipse.eclipse
Version:               3.8 (3.8)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           eclipse [1032]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-12-23 22:49:53.824 -0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.2 (16C67)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        7EB9EBB2-D3B9-8F3B-EC33-B888DDDA4C54


Time Awake Since Boot: 1900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x3c:
--> 
__TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100004000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /var/folders/*/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffb27d3544 CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName + 36
1   org.eclipse.eclipse             0x00000001000030bd findSymbol + 66
2   org.eclipse.eclipse             0x00000001000018be original_main + 1572
3   org.eclipse.eclipse             0x0000000100001f7d main + 1230
4   org.eclipse.eclipse             0x0000000100001158 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffc7edd1e0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffc7edd1e0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffc7edd1e0 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x000070000965bb40 0 + 123145459972928

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000610000020140  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx:     0x6974696e49746573  rdx: 0x0000000000000006
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000610000020140  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff9b0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff580
   r8: 0x736772416c616974   r9: 0x0000000000000600  r10: 0x0000000000000002  r11: 0x00007fffb27d3520
  r12: 0x00000001000043f8  r13: 0x00006100000a0000  r14:   0x0000610000020140  r15: 0x02b18d72892400a7
  rip: 0x00007fffb27d3544  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000000010d7c7000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000170
Trap Number:     133
```

Comment: While I'm aware this doesn't directly answer your question, do you have any particular reason for using Eclipse over Android Studio? Google dropped support for Eclipse about 18 months ago. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html?m=1

Comment: Yes I am using it because Im doing these tutorials from an android game development book I just purchased that requires it.  Do you know how to read the crash log? This is the first time I ever had to deal with this and I just cant figure it out, thanks very much.

Comment: it was working completely fine until I deleted the whole thing and re installed it I tried looking in the cache to see if I could find anything but nothing

Comment: update I just got it to work with running it from the terminal clean but it still wont open if i try to click on the app icon only from the terminal

Comment: @izzyMachado can you solve this issue?

Comment: @NekakKinich I wasnt able to solve it, but I did get eclipse to run fine when I ran it from the terminal.  not sure I think it had to do with me deleting it then re installing and the system probably got some things confused.  but if you run from terminal everything works fine

Comment: @izzyMachado thank you :)

Comment: @NekakKinich no problem ! here is the link that helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853053/how-to-run-eclipse-clean-on-a-mac