# Eclipse app opening but not able to open files after updating to macOS Big Sur

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-11

So I recently updated to macOS Big Sur, and after the update Eclipse stopped working. Originally it refused to open entirely, so I took a look at this post: [Not able to run Eclipse on macOS Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62647625/not-able-to-run-eclipse-on-macos-big-sur)

I tried to fix my issue by setting my JAVA_HOME variable (which was previously unset) to the version of JDK I have installed (11.0.1), ie doing this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

After this I was able to open Eclipse, but it won't open any documents or code, and the UI was generally glitchy and irresponsive. My Eclipse window looks like this:

[image: Eclipse window]

As you can see the window appears to open correctly aside from an error message that pops up every time I open the app. However I'm not able to open any of the folders in the project explorer, or actually use any features really.

I also checked Eclipse for updates and found one update that I promptly installed, and I tried changing the `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist` file as suggested in the post I mentioned previously. I also tried downloading JDK 1.8.0_281 as used in the post and changing my JAVA_HOME variable to the new path but with no success.

I don't do much development with Eclipse or with Java so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

*UPDATE: I saved backups of my projects, then did a full uninstall and reinstall of Eclipse (and downloaded a newer version this time) and everything appears to work fine now!*

Comment: Have you tried [launching Eclipse with -clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853053/how-to-run-eclipse-clean-on-a-mac) (which has saved me in the past).   AND when you say not able to open files - what error are you getting (sometimes a refresh can help?)?

Comment: Just tried that, didn't notice any change unfortunately. When I try to open a project folder, simply nothing happens. When I try opening a .java file it gives me some indication that it is trying to open (center editing area turns gray), but no errors.

Comment: IIRC there are a whole heap of new permissions in BigSuR - perhaps go into Security & Privacy, and add eclipse to the "Files and Folders" permission. [My BigSur machines are all off at the moment - might be slightly different - but I know I had to grant access to terminal before I could see some things in terminal (nothing to do with eclipse just the impact of permissions)]. Oh and being an "admin" doesn't change this - the permissions are separate to normal file permissions

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is it? You'd want one that came out *after* Big Sur, like 4.18/2020-12. Your Java release looks a few patch levels behind as well, and should be up to date for the same compatibility reasons.

Comment: You are able to view / read the directories / files an other way - i.e. just confirming there isn't a real file permissons problem?  AND in eclipse does the project think it's a java project (properties) [i.e. has a J overlaid on it]? If you create a NEW java project - does that work when you create files?

Comment: ^ just updated the question, it seems like it was some sort of issue with the version of eclipse being incompatible with Big Sur? Not sure, either way thanks for the input!

Comment: Eclipse 2012-12 was the first release to run properly on macOS 11 (Big Sur), all previous releases have issues.